# Conditional output with multiple variables based on filled input fields

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small UTM-builder tool which outputs a long URL based upon text which the user has entered in multiple input fields like this:

```
<input id="utm_website" placeholder="https://" onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()">
```

The form that I'm using has 6 input fields, the first 3 are required the last 3 fields can be used conditionally. For example field 1,2,3,5 and 6 have input and field 5 has no input.

I got this all working except for one thing. Right now I've created multiple conditions but they only work if the input fields are filled in a logical way like fields 1-3, 1-4, 1-5 and 1-6.

```
function formChanged() {    
        
        // Get all input values         
        let utmWebsite = document.getElementById('utm_website').value; //required value
        let utmSource = document.getElementById('utm_source').value; //required value
        let utmMedium = document.getElementById('utm_campaign').value; //required value
        let utmName = document.getElementById('utm_name').value;
        let utmTerm = document.getElementById('utm_term').value;
        let utmContent = document.getElementById('utm_content').value;
        
        // Enrich all input values with UTM tags
        let enrichSource = '?utm_source=' + utmSource;      
        let enrichMedium = '&utm_medium=' + utmMedium;
        let enrichName = '&utm_campaign=' + utmName;
        let enrichTerm = '&utm_term=' + utmTerm;
        let enrichContent = '&utm_content=' + utmContent;

        // Combine them all if at least website, source and medium are defined
        
        if( utmWebsite && utmSource && utmMedium ){
        utmLink = utmWebsite + enrichSource + enrichMedium
                    
        // Output the UTM link
        document.getElementById('utm_result').innerHTML=utmLink;            
        }
        
        // Also add name to the output if defined
        if( utmWebsite && utmSource && utmMedium && utmName ){
        utmLinkName = utmWebsite + enrichSource + enrichMedium + enrichName
                    
        // Output the UTM link
        document.getElementById('utm_result').innerHTML=utmLinkName;        
        }
        
        // Also add name & term to the output if defined
        if( utmWebsite && utmSource && utmMedium && utmName && utmTerm ){
        utmLinkNameTerm = utmWebsite + enrichSource + enrichMedium + enrichName + enrichTerm
                    
        // Output the UTM link
        document.getElementById('utm_result').innerHTML=utmLinkNameTerm;
        }
        
        // Also add name & term & content to the output if defined
        if( utmWebsite && utmSource && utmMedium && utmName && utmTerm && utmContent ){
        utmLinkNameTermContent = utmWebsite + enrichSource + enrichMedium + enrichName + enrichTerm + enrichContent
                    
        // Output the UTM link
        document.getElementById('utm_result').innerHTML=utmLinkNameTermContent;         
        }           
        
    };
```

I'm quite new to JavaScript and my 'solution' feels too complicated and doesn't work if one of two of the  non-required fields are used in a random order. I've already search for a solution but I'm probably using the wrong search terms due to my lack of JavaScript knowlegde.

Is there a way to change to code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append the fields if they are defined, rather than creating a whole new URL string each time.

First check to see if your required params are defined like you are doing.

```
if( utmWebsite && utmSource && utmMedium ){
    utmLink = utmWebsite + enrichSource + enrichMedium;
}
```

Then inside the same block, check each optional one and append it if defined.

```
if( utmWebsite && utmSource && utmMedium ){
    utmLink = utmWebsite + enrichSource + enrichMedium;
    
    if(utmName) utmLink += enrichName;
    if(utmTerm) utmLink += enrichTerm;
    if(utmContent) utmLink += enrichContent;

    document.getElementById('utm_result').innerHTML=utmLink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @David Works really well and didn't knew about the `+=` operator until now.